# Django model multiple updates with objects' own data?

Tags: python, django, django-models

I've seen code in the django docs that does multiple object updates like

```
Entry.objects.filter(pub_date__year=2010).update(comments_on=False)
```

Is there a way to update multiple objects by updating each object's value?  For example, add one to all the articles that a user has read

```
# so it does something like this?
Entry.objects.filter(user_has_read).update(views+=1)
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, by using [F() objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#query-expressions):

```
from django.db.models import F

Entry.objects.filter(user_has_read).update(views=F('views') + 1)
```

See [updating multiple objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#updating-multiple-objects-at-once), second to last paragraph.